# How to embed php code in min.js file

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am creating charts using javascript library chartjs. For this, I have a bootstrap template having chart.min.js file having charts in it but these charts are not built up by data from database. So how do i embed my php code in that min.js file to replace the charts by my charts. I need to built them by data from database table. Here is the code from bootstrap template i.e. chart.min.js file:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily='-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif',
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor="#292b2c";var ctx=document.getElementById("myAreaChart"),
myLineChart=new Chart(ctx,{
 type:"line",
 
 data:{labels:["Mar 10","Mar 2","Mar 3","Mar 4","Mar 5","Mar 6","Mar 7","Mar 8","Mar 9","Mar 10","Mar 11","Mar 12","Mar 13"],
 datasets:[{label:"Sessions",
 lineTension:.3,
 backgroundColor:"rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
 borderColor:"rgba(2,117,216,1)",
 pointRadius:5,
 pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(2,117,216,1)",
 pointBorderColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
 pointHoverRadius:5,
 pointHoverBackgroundColor:"rgba(2,117,216,1)",
 pointHitRadius:20,
 pointBorderWidth:2,
 data:[1e4,30162,26263,18394,18287,28682,31274,33259,25849,24159,32651,31984,38451]}]},
 options:{scales:{xAxes:[{time:{unit:"date"},
 gridLines:{display:!1},ticks:{maxTicksLimit:7}}],
 yAxes:[{ticks:{min:0,max:4e4,maxTicksLimit:5},
 gridLines:{color:"rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)"}}]},legend:{display:!1}}})
```

And here is the code that I want to replace in that min.js file:

```html
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbname='chartjs';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';
try{
 $dbcon=new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
 $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $ex){
 die($ex->getMessage());
}
$stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM chartjs");
$stmt->execute();
$json=[];
$json2=[];
while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 extract($row);
 $json[]=$title;
 $json2[]= (int)$amounts;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Charts</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="height: 50%">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
 ctx.height = 100;
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Amounts per Title",
            backgroundColor: 'grey',
            borderColor: 'black',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($json2); ?>,
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {

    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that, you don't embed php in a javascript, it is the other way round, you embed js in a php file.

PHP runs in the server and it is served to the client as html (+js +css), you should include your min.js in the php file wherever you want to render it the same way you are including Chart.min.js